# Using react-select with redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am trying to use react-select with redux-form. My code is as follows:

```
const DropdownComponent = ({
  input, options, name, id, placeholder,
}) => (
  <Select
    id={id}
    name={name}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    value={input.value}
    options={options}
    onChange={input.onChange}
    onBlurResetsInput={false}
    onCloseResetsInput={false}
    {...input}
    onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value.value)}
  />
);
```

The options that I am sending is as:

```
const options = [
  { value: '1', label: '%' },
  { value: '2', label: '$' },
];
```

This works fine when I select a value, but the moment the select loses focus, the value is cleared onBlur. Any suggestions as to what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this maybe the culprit: `onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value.value)}`

I think that extra `.value` is undefined.

Comment: I need that extra .value or else the field value is returned as object { value: '1', label: '%' }